# waitpid() failed: no such file or directory

Tags: c, unix

I tried to call exec() in child process, and wait in parent process. It works fine when I used 'wait()' in parent process. But I like to get the status code of child process so I use waitpid() and it failed to wait. I don't know why, please help, appreciate!

```
int runcgi(int socket, char *uri, char *dir)
{   
    pid_t pid; 
    int status = 0;
    char command[MAXPATHLEN];
    
    snprintf(command, MAXPATHLEN, "%s%s", dir, strsep(&uri, "?"));
    printf("%s\n", command);
    
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {   
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "Error forking");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {   
        if (dup2(socket, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        {    
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error duping STDOUT_FILENO");
            status = -1;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        if (dup2(socket, STDERR_FILENO) < 0)
        {    
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error duping STDERR_FILENO");
            status = -1;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        if (setenv("PATH", dir, 1) != 0)
        {    
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to set PATH=%s", dir);
            status = -1;
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to set PATH=%s", dir);
        }
        
        if (uri != NULL && strlen(uri) > 0)
        {   
            char *var;
            while ((var = strsep(&uri, "&")) != NULL)
            {   
                if (putenv(var) == -1)
                {    
                    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to set env %s", var);
                    status = -1;
                    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to set env %s", var);
                }
            }
        }
        
        execlp(command, basename(command), (char *)0);
        status = -1;
    }
    
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
    {   
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "waitpid failed");
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "waitpid failed");
    }
    
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {   
        return WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }

//  (void)wait(NULL);
    return status;
}
```

The strange thing about this is, I got 'no such file or directory' when I check errno.

Comment: After `execlp()`, you should report an error and exit rather than continuing as if nothing went wrong.  I suspect you may find that it is the child process failing to execute the command and running into an error with `waitpid()` because it has no child.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler still the same outcome after I added _exit() in child process

Comment: Well, you've not provided an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  That means we can't easily reproduce your problem.  Since you're busy setting the `$PATH` environment variable, it would be a good idea to print out what it is set to.  That could be a major factor.  You also have not shown us the printed value of `command`.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the code that passes the `status` to its parent? The child sets `status` to `-1` but then doesn't do anything with it! Did you want `_exit(status);` in the child?

You're getting an error because the child is trying to wait for a child it doesn't
have. The error "no such file or directory" here just means the PID doesn't correspond to any process in the child because the child gets a zero return from `fork`.

Here's what happens in the child:

```
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        ... // lots of code here
        execlp(command, basename(command), (char *)0);
        status = -1;
    }
    
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
```

Notice that if `execlp` fails, you set `status` to `-1`. But then you don't do anything with it. You then call `waitpid` *in the child*, but `pid` is zero here! You are missing a call to `_exit` in the child.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's really something I missed. But I still got the same outcome after I added _exit() in child process. Even if the execlp() succeed, the waitpid() still fails.

Comment: @mykox I'd need to see what you did exactly to figure out what's still wrong. By the way, you should not use `exit` in the child. You should use `_exit`. You don't want to call the parent's cleanup handlers in the child.